# How to put figures in LaTex in \documentclass[preprint,12pt,authoryear]{elsarticle}

Tags: graphics, floats

It said "

```
%% For including figures, graphicx.sty has been loaded in
%% elsarticle.cls
```

I do not know how to use that effectively. can you provide a worked example here.

For example

```
\usepackage{epsfig}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{placeins}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Damage at }
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig1.pdf}
\end{figure} 
\FloatBarrier
```

How should I place the figure within manuscript. Or do I need to bring them at the end of manuscript? (attention to elsarticle requirement). The code above is currently place figure randomly in somewhere doc. why?

Comment: Latex does not support tif, convert it into, say, png and include that

Comment: @ daleif As far as I know .tif gives a good quality of resolution in a hard copy version of publication. .png is the worst, is it not?

Comment: I haven't had any problems with it.

Comment: As long as the source is of good quality. Crappy we images will always be Crappy no matter the format. Have had good results scanning hi res images (diagrams from old books) on our photo copier, then converting it into png to be used in pdf for printing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt,authoryear]{elsarticle}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\caption{abc} \label{fig:abc}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{<filename>}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Simply use a real filename, of an image file encoded in a supported format, instead of `<filename>`.

Comment: @ Mico, let me try it NOW! It sounds very straightforward.

Comment: @ Mico \begin{figure}
\caption{Damage at }
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig1.tif}
\end{figure} why it does not work?

Comment: @Mohammad - the `tif` format isn't supported. Can you convert the tif file to a pdf format?

Comment: @ Mico, it is possible but how about its quality in printed version?

Comment: @Mohammad - Sorry, but I have no knowledge whatsoever of the pros and cons of various graphics formats. Maybe raise this question in a different group?

Comment: @ Mico, it still has an error after I convert .tif to pdf. Why? Should I call any package etc at beginning of doc?

Comment: @Mohammad Exactly which error?

Comment: @ daleif pdfTeX error: /Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex (file ./sample.pdf): xpdf: reading 
PDF image failed
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

Comment: @ Mico, I think No. The answer is fine. You are asking to put simply a .filename.pdf in above code and it is supposed to work! correct? but it is not. as I copied error above.

Comment: Photo is changed it does work now. I think the issues was related to Pdf conversion.

Comment: @ Mico and  @daleif How should I place the figure within manuscript. Or do I need to bring them at the end of manuscript? (attention to elsarticle requirement). The code above is currently place figure randomly in somewhere doc. why?

Comment: @Mohammad - LaTeX does *nothing* randomly. For an in-depth discussion of LaTeX's float placement algorithm, see [Frank Mittelbach's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39020/5001) to the question [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/5001)

Comment: @ Mico, it is good to know this link. I realized that \FloatBarrier is also useful to use.